# The execute command failed due to an internal error execute-dommand for ECS on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I bumped into this error

`An error occurred (TargetNotConnectedException) when calling the ExecuteCommand operation: The execute command failed due to an internal error. Try again later.`

when using execute-command to the container of ECS on EC2.

These are my log.

```
% aws ecs execute-command --cluster mytest-dev-ec2-cluster --container mytest-nginx-container --interactive --command '/bin/bash' --task  c8ae7c4af555400aa54a446a10edf4f5 --debug
2023-05-12 21:21:40,289 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/2.11.15 Python/3.11.3 Darwin/22.3.0 source/arm64
2023-05-12 21:21:40,289 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['ecs', 'execute-command', '--cluster', 'mytest-dev-ec2-cluster', '--container', 'mytest-nginx-container', '--interactive', '--command', '/bin/bash', '--task', 'c8ae7c4af555400aa54a446a10edf4f5', '--debug']
2023-05-12 21:21:40,297 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <function add_s3 at 0x103d9db20>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,297 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <function add_ddb at 0x1038ca8e0>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,297 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <bound method BasicCommand.add_command of <class 'awscli.customizations.configure.configure.ConfigureCommand'>>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,297 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <function change_name at 0x1037c5800>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,297 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <function change_name at 0x103854d60>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,297 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <function alias_opsworks_cm at 0x103db5580>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,297 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <function add_history_commands at 0x103929a80>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,297 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <bound method BasicCommand.add_command of <class 'awscli.customizations.devcommands.CLIDevCommand'>>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,297 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x103db4540>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,297 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler <bound method AliasSubCommandInjector.on_building_command_table of <awscli.alias.AliasSubCommandInjector object at 0x103e5b910>>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,297 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/data/cli.json
2023-05-12 21:21:40,298 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event top-level-args-parsed: calling handler <function resolve_types at 0x1039f53a0>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,298 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event top-level-args-parsed: calling handler <function no_sign_request at 0x1039f56c0>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,298 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event top-level-args-parsed: calling handler <function resolve_verify_ssl at 0x1039f5620>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,298 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event top-level-args-parsed: calling handler <function resolve_cli_read_timeout at 0x1039f5800>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,298 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event top-level-args-parsed: calling handler <function resolve_cli_connect_timeout at 0x1039f5760>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,298 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event top-level-args-parsed: calling handler <built-in method update of dict object at 0x103e58ec0>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,298 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/2.11.15 Python/3.11.3 Darwin/22.3.0 source/arm64 prompt/off
2023-05-12 21:21:40,298 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['ecs', 'execute-command', '--cluster', 'mytest-dev-ec2-cluster', '--container', 'mytest-nginx-container', '--interactive', '--command', '/bin/bash', '--task', 'c8ae7c4af555400aa54a446a10edf4f5', '--debug']
2023-05-12 21:21:40,298 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function add_timestamp_parser at 0x103d9e5c0>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,298 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function register_uri_param_handler at 0x1034a1da0>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,298 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function add_binary_formatter at 0x103e16840>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,298 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function no_pager_handler at 0x103492520>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,298 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function inject_assume_role_provider_cache at 0x1034e7d80>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,299 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - IMDS ENDPOINT: http://169.254.169.254/
2023-05-12 21:21:40,303 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function attach_history_handler at 0x103929260>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,303 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function inject_json_file_cache at 0x1038be980>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,311 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/data/ecs/2014-11-13/service-2.json
2023-05-12 21:21:40,314 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.ecs: calling handler <function inject_commands at 0x1039cd580>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,315 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.ecs: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x103db4540>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,322 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/data/ecs/2014-11-13/waiters-2.json
2023-05-12 21:21:40,322 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.ecs: calling handler <bound method AliasSubCommandInjector.on_building_command_table of <awscli.alias.AliasSubCommandInjector object at 0x103e5b910>>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,322 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - OrderedDict([('cluster', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x10401aa10>), ('container', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x10401ab90>), ('command', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x10401ac90>), ('interactive', <awscli.arguments.BooleanArgument object at 0x10401add0>), ('no-interactive', <awscli.arguments.BooleanArgument object at 0x10401ae10>), ('task', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x10401af10>)])
2023-05-12 21:21:40,322 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <function add_streaming_output_arg at 0x103d9ec00>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,322 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <function rename_arg.<locals>._rename_arg at 0x103e32700>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,322 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <function rename_arg.<locals>._rename_arg at 0x103e327a0>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,322 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <function add_cli_input_json at 0x1034fc860>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,322 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <function add_cli_input_yaml at 0x1034fcae0>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,322 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <function unify_paging_params at 0x1038cb060>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,330 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/data/ecs/2014-11-13/paginators-1.json
2023-05-12 21:21:40,330 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <function add_generate_skeleton at 0x1039cfa60>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,330 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <bound method OverrideRequiredArgsArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.cliinput.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x102c9a210>>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,330 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <bound method OverrideRequiredArgsArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.cliinput.CliInputYAMLArgument object at 0x10401c410>>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,330 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x1040011d0>>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,330 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.ecs_execute-command: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x103db4540>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,330 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.ecs_execute-command: calling handler <bound method AliasSubCommandInjector.on_building_command_table of <awscli.alias.AliasSubCommandInjector object at 0x103e5b910>>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecs.execute-command.cluster: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x103e60310>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x1034bf310>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - awscli.arguments - DEBUG - Unpacked value of 'mytest-dev-ec2-cluster' for parameter "cluster": 'mytest-dev-ec2-cluster'
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecs.execute-command.container: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x103e60310>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x1034bf310>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - awscli.arguments - DEBUG - Unpacked value of 'mytest-nginx-container' for parameter "container": 'mytest-nginx-container'
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecs.execute-command.command: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x103e60310>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x1034bf310>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - awscli.arguments - DEBUG - Unpacked value of '/bin/bash' for parameter "command": '/bin/bash'
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecs.execute-command.interactive: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x103e60310>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecs.execute-command.task: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x103e60310>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x1034bf310>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - awscli.arguments - DEBUG - Unpacked value of 'c8ae7c4af555400aa54a446a10edf4f5' for parameter "task": 'c8ae7c4af555400aa54a446a10edf4f5'
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecs.execute-command.cli-input-json: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x103e60310>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecs.execute-command.cli-input-yaml: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x103e60310>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecs.execute-command.generate-cli-skeleton: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x103e60310>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <bound method CliInputArgument.add_to_call_parameters of <awscli.customizations.cliinput.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x102c9a210>>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <bound method CliInputArgument.add_to_call_parameters of <awscli.customizations.cliinput.CliInputYAMLArgument object at 0x10401c410>>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,331 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.ecs.execute-command: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.generate_skeleton of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x1040011d0>>

The Session Manager plugin was installed successfully. Use the AWS CLI to start a session.

2023-05-12 21:21:40,377 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: env
2023-05-12 21:21:40,377 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2023-05-12 21:21:40,377 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role-with-web-identity
2023-05-12 21:21:40,377 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: sso
2023-05-12 21:21:40,377 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
2023-05-12 21:21:40,377 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2023-05-12 21:21:40,378 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/data/endpoints.json
2023-05-12 21:21:40,383 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x102754180>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,391 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/data/ecs/2014-11-13/endpoint-rule-set-1.json
2023-05-12 21:21:40,391 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/data/partitions.json
2023-05-12 21:21:40,392 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.ecs: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x10269f2e0>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,394 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Setting ecs timeout as (60, 60)
2023-05-12 21:21:40,395 - MainThread - botocore.regions - DEBUG - Calling endpoint provider with parameters: {'Region': 'ap-northeast-1', 'UseDualStack': False, 'UseFIPS': False}
2023-05-12 21:21:40,395 - MainThread - botocore.regions - DEBUG - Endpoint provider result: https://ecs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
2023-05-12 21:21:40,395 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event provide-client-params.ecs.ExecuteCommand: calling handler <function base64_decode_input_blobs at 0x103e168e0>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,395 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.ecs.ExecuteCommand: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x102756520>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,395 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-call.ecs.ExecuteCommand: calling handler <function inject_api_version_header_if_needed at 0x102770040>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,395 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Making request for OperationModel(name=ExecuteCommand) with params: {'url_path': '/', 'query_string': '', 'method': 'POST', 'headers': {'X-Amz-Target': 'AmazonEC2ContainerServiceV20141113.ExecuteCommand', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'User-Agent': 'aws-cli/2.11.15 Python/3.11.3 Darwin/22.3.0 source/arm64 prompt/off command/ecs.execute-command'}, 'body': b'{"cluster": "mytest-dev-ec2-cluster", "container": "mytest-nginx-container", "command": "/bin/bash", "interactive": true, "task": "c8ae7c4af555400aa54a446a10edf4f5"}', 'url': 'https://ecs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/', 'context': {'client_region': 'ap-northeast-1', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x10251db10>, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'auth_type': None}}
2023-05-12 21:21:40,395 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event request-created.ecs.ExecuteCommand: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x103fd56d0>>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,395 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-signer.ecs.ExecuteCommand: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x1027563e0>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,395 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2023-05-12 21:21:40,395 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
POST
/

content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
host:ecs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20230512T122140Z
x-amz-target:AmazonEC2ContainerServiceV20141113.ExecuteCommand

content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target
03ab76c8fbf759b519a693a41fbf4a2bae219f12bc71a00dfc9f66661e192129
2023-05-12 21:21:40,395 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20230512T122140Z
20230512/ap-northeast-1/ecs/aws4_request
4d971ff4ad00e752c997eb6ea9bfa1f9037575d7842f70d0ce26452d58a88007
2023-05-12 21:21:40,395 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature:
ce8890a3f555eb2422a0119e1b50a7890b236d3154bc0b242013db34e0f2efec
2023-05-12 21:21:40,395 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=POST, url=https://ecs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/, headers={'X-Amz-Target': b'AmazonEC2ContainerServiceV20141113.ExecuteCommand', 'Content-Type': b'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'User-Agent': b'aws-cli/2.11.15 Python/3.11.3 Darwin/22.3.0 source/arm64 prompt/off command/ecs.execute-command', 'X-Amz-Date': b'20230512T122140Z', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAZ3YPMLAS3IPWM4OZ/20230512/ap-northeast-1/ecs/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=ce8890a3f555eb2422a0119e1b50a7890b236d3154bc0b242013db34e0f2efec', 'Content-Length': '157'}>
2023-05-12 21:21:40,396 - MainThread - botocore.httpsession - DEBUG - Certificate path: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/cacert.pem
2023-05-12 21:21:40,396 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): ecs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:443
2023-05-12 21:21:41,512 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - https://ecs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:443 "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 122
2023-05-12 21:21:41,514 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response headers: {'x-amzn-RequestId': '0b8ae4f8-6275-446a-98c9-0cfdf0801300', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'Content-Length': '122', 'Date': 'Fri, 12 May 2023 12:21:41 GMT', 'Connection': 'close'}
2023-05-12 21:21:41,514 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response body:
b'{"__type":"TargetNotConnectedException","message":"The execute command failed due to an internal error. Try again later."}'
2023-05-12 21:21:41,517 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response headers: {'x-amzn-RequestId': '0b8ae4f8-6275-446a-98c9-0cfdf0801300', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'Content-Length': '122', 'Date': 'Fri, 12 May 2023 12:21:41 GMT', 'Connection': 'close'}
2023-05-12 21:21:41,517 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response body:
b'{"__type":"TargetNotConnectedException","message":"The execute command failed due to an internal error. Try again later."}'
2023-05-12 21:21:41,517 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.ecs.ExecuteCommand: calling handler <bound method RetryHandler.needs_retry of <botocore.retries.standard.RetryHandler object at 0x104478810>>
2023-05-12 21:21:41,517 - MainThread - botocore.retries.standard - DEBUG - Not retrying request.
2023-05-12 21:21:41,518 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.ecs.ExecuteCommand: calling handler <bound method RetryQuotaChecker.release_retry_quota of <botocore.retries.standard.RetryQuotaChecker object at 0x10446f690>>
2023-05-12 21:21:41,518 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exception caught in main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 460, in main
    return command_table[parsed_args.command](remaining, parsed_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 595, in __call__
    return command_table[parsed_args.operation](remaining, parsed_globals)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 798, in __call__
    return self._operation_caller.invoke(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/customizations/ecs/executecommand.py", line 91, in invoke
    response = client.execute_command(**parameters)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/client.py", line 341, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/awscli/2.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awscli/botocore/client.py", line 697, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.TargetNotConnectedException: An error occurred (TargetNotConnectedException) when calling the ExecuteCommand operation: The execute command failed due to an internal error. Try again later.

An error occurred (TargetNotConnectedException) when calling the ExecuteCommand operation: The execute command failed due to an internal error. Try again later.
```

and I have checked the environment with `check-ecs-exec.sh` but looks there is no problem.

```
$sh ./check-ecs-exec.sh mytest-dev-ec2-cluster c8ae7c4af555400aa54a446a10edf4f5
-------------------------------------------------------------
Prerequisites for check-ecs-exec.sh v0.7
-------------------------------------------------------------
  jq      | OK (/opt/homebrew/bin/jq)
  AWS CLI | OK (/opt/homebrew/bin/aws)

-------------------------------------------------------------
Prerequisites for the AWS CLI to use ECS Exec
-------------------------------------------------------------
  AWS CLI Version        | OK (aws-cli/2.11.15 Python/3.11.3 Darwin/22.3.0 source/arm64 prompt/off)
  Session Manager Plugin | OK (1.2.295.0)

-------------------------------------------------------------
Checks on ECS task and other resources
-------------------------------------------------------------
Region : ap-northeast-1
Cluster: mytest-dev-ec2-cluster
Task   : c8ae7c4af555400aa54a446a10edf4f5
-------------------------------------------------------------
  Cluster Configuration  | Audit Logging Not Configured
  Can I ExecuteCommand?  | arn:aws:iam::678100228133:user/viraladmin
     ecs:ExecuteCommand: allowed
     ssm:StartSession denied?: allowed
  Task Status            | RUNNING
  Launch Type            | EC2
  ECS Agent Version      | 1.51.0
  Exec Enabled for Task  | OK
  Container-Level Checks | 
    ----------
      Managed Agent Status
    ----------
         1. RUNNING for "mytest-django-container"
         2. RUNNING for "mytest-nginx-container"
    ----------
      Init Process Enabled (oldevecsTaskDefinition4BE5F675:9)
    ----------
         1. Disabled - "mytest-nginx-container"
         2. Disabled - "mytest-django-container"
    ----------
      Read-Only Root Filesystem (oldevecsTaskDefinition4BE5F675:9)
    ----------
         1. Disabled - "mytest-nginx-container"
         2. Disabled - "mytest-django-container"
  Task Role Permissions  | arn:aws:iam::678100228133:role/mytest-dev-ecs-TaskDefinitionTaskRoleFD40A61D-RTJJFY545YFV
     ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel: allowed
     ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel: allowed
     ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel: allowed
     ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel: allowed
  VPC Endpoints          | SKIPPED (vpc-7b01071c - No additional VPC endpoints required)
  Environment Variables  | (oldevecsTaskDefinition4BE5F675:9)
       1. container "mytest-nginx-container"
       - AWS_ACCESS_KEY: not defined
       - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: not defined
       - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: not defined
       2. container "mytest-django-container"
       - AWS_ACCESS_KEY: not defined
       - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: not defined
       - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: not defined
```